# What is the good pattern to check http response in one place in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building an app with flutter and it needs to send http request to backend server in many places. Each request will have a token which is used by backend to check users' authentication. If the token is expired, flutter needs to alert users and route to `/login` view to ask users' credential. 
Since there are many http requests in the app I don't want to check the token expire in every place. I am looking for a way where happens globally in flutter app to check every http response.  I am from `react` world where I can create a middleware in the app to check every http response status. Is there a similar pattern in flutter that does the job?

My app needs to send requests to both rest and graphql endpoints. Is there a middleware works for both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package or [Chopper](https://pub.dev/packages/chopper) with interceptors. 
Check response in every request(in interceptor) and if it 401 just navigate to LoginPage

Comment: for graph ql you need to use
https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter
The best library for flutter

Comment: Yes I am using this library but it doesn't seem it support interceptors